# При переходе на страницу списка элементов отдаётся 404

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, http-status-code-404

При переходе на страницу списка элементов вида *https://site.ru/category/subcategory/* отдаётся страница с ошибкой 404. Использую шаблон category.php. На сайте установлены плагины Elementor и JetEngine, есть подозрение на них, но в их настройках ничего про адреса страниц нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: обратитесь в поддержку хостинг-провайдера, никто не видит ваш category.php, непонятно какой у вас веб-сервер, какие у него настройки, пробовали ли отключать плагины - если нет, то попробуйте отключить, а потом спрашивайте

Comment: Я наверно не особо понятно сформулировал, но суть вот в чём: есть страница _https://site.ru/services/_ на которой происходит получение подкатегорий, которые являются подразделами (таксономией) пользовательского типа записи и при переходе на страницу раздела со списком элементов вида _https://site.ru/services/subvervice/_ как раз и отдаётся страница с ошибкой 404. Плагины отключал, не помогло.